# Comment savoir utiliser H muet ou H aspiré dans les noms de gens ?

Tags: usage, prononciation, noms-propres, h-aspiré

Aujourd'hui j'ai cherché si le nom "Harry" utilise un H muet ou un H aspiré. Heureusement j'ai trouvé "**d'Harry** Potter" et "Mariage **d'Harry** et Meghan" enligne qui m'a donné le bon réponse.

Comment puis-je trouver le même chose pour tous les noms de gens qui commence avec H ? Les dictionnaires n'ont pas ces mots.

Par exemple, l'ancien premier ministre australien Harold Holt:

> Le gouvernement d'Harold Holt
>
> Le gouvernement de Harold Holt
>
> Le gouvernement d'Holt
>
> Le gouvernement de Holt

Comment puis-je trouver quelles sont les bonnes phrases ? Est-ce qu'une ressource existe avec tels noms ?

Je parle l'anglais couramment mais pas encore le français.

Comment: En fait pour Harry, qui vient de Henri, vous trouverez la règle ici: https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Henri. Dans les romans traduits de J.K. Rowling, le H de Harry est aspiré.

Answer (score 8):

Vous trouverez "les bonnes phrases" dans tout dictionnaire des noms propres.
Le problème est que ces dictionnaires se contredisent parfois et qu'avec le temps l'usage change.

Par exemple, au XIXe siècle l'élision était de coutume pour Hugo, aujourd'hui l'hiatus est dominant.

On pourrait être tenté de chercher l'indication dans les dictionnaires de noms communs pour les mots dérivés, pour l'exemple ci-dessus (*hugolien*, *hugotique*, *hugolâtre*... ) mais là encore... les dictionnaires se contredisent voire manquent de logique.

On serait fondé à croire que les noms propres sont allés à l'économie et que donc, si un H existe à l'initiale il est nécessairement aspiré (ce qui est je crois le cas au moins dans toutes les langues germaniques) maintenant je n'ai jamais lu la baie d'Hudson écrite autrement ni la saint Hubert prononcée autrement qu'avec une liaison.

Pas de référence donc, pas de règle absolue possible. Je crois que, comme pour les toponymes pour lesquels l'usage des locaux doit prévaloir, c'est l'usage par celui qui est nommé qui doit prévaloir.
Et... quand on ne les connait pas... on fait : Comme on veut!

**EDIT :** J'ai écrit plus haut, beaucoup trop hâtivement, un truc du genre :
«...*aspiré (ce qui est le cas dans les langues germaniques)*»

Eh bien... j'ai écrit là une grosse bêtise qui n'est pas sans importance relativement à notre sujet.
Si fait!

Les H à l'initiale des noms germaniques ne sont pas du tout *aspirés* puisqu'ils sont rien moins que... tout le contraire! C'est encore à dire : **expirés**!

Ils s'entendent très exactement comme dans nos interjections *Ho! Hola! Hue!*
Comme encore dans *Hideux* ou *Honte* quand, fâché, on fait porter l'accent sur la première syllabe.

À la différence de notre H *aspiré* qui ne s'entend pas, le H *expiré* s'entend donc lui très bien, ce qui fait que, prononçant comme il se doit les noms germaniques, c'est à dire à l'allemande, il n'y a pas hiatus dans *de Heine, de Heidegger, de Hitler, de Hanover...* D'où l'écriture par principe : **de** + H...

Les divergences relevées en commentaires par Gilles (que je remercie vivement car c'est lui qui a mis le doigt sur mon erreur) peuvent s'expliquer très logiquement :

Avec *Hanovre*, on n'utilise à l'évidence plus la prononciation allemande (sinon on dirait *Hanover*) *Hanovre* est l'orthographe francisée => prononciation française => plus d'expiration => risque d'hiatus => d'Hanovre !

*Heine* ? *Heidegger* ? Ceux qui ont capacité pour écrire à leur propos les ont nécessairement lus en allemand. => prononciation à l'allemande par habitude et respect => pas hiatus.

Hitler ? je suis persuadé qu'il se serait contenté d'écrire des poésies, on dirait encore les poésies **de** Hitler... Ayant décidé de concerner malgré eux nombre de locuteurs, radio, journalistes non germanistes... la prononciation de son nom s'est vite francisée => hiatus => d'Hitler.

Merci encore à Gilles.

Comment: C'est marrant, on pourrait aussi discuter de *hiatus*…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Ha oui! Absolument *le hiatus* ou *l'hiatus* ... ;)

Comment: Hmmm. “La philosophie de Heidegger” mais “l'armée d'Hitler”. “La poésie de Heine”. “La philosophie de Hume”. “L'électeur de/d'Hanovre” ([le H est devenu aspiré au 19e](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9lecteur+de+Hanovre%2C%C3%A9lecteur+d%27Hanovre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9lecteur%20de%20Hanovre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9lecteur%20d%27%20Hanovre%3B%2Cc0)). Alors que pour baie de/d'Hudson c'est l'inverse: “de Hudson” a disparu au début du 19e. Pour Hirohito c'est plutôt *de* mais on trouve aussi *d'*.

Comment: @Gilles : Oui! Absolument! Pas de règle. Que des usages qui, comme tous les usages changent avec le temps. On a side note, merci pour ton commentaire, les exemples que tu cites m'ont fait réaliser que j'ai écrit ci-contre une **grosse** *bêtise*. Je la corrigerai ASAP. KUDOS pour celui qui la déniche avant!

Comment: @jlliagre : Ce n'est pas parce que tu as le droit de modifier mes contributions que je trouve pour autant cela bienvenu. Il n'y avait strictement rien d'incorrect dans la formulation que tu as modifiée au profit d'un style que je trouve pour ma part *LOURDINGUE* et qui, en tout cas ne me correspond pas!

Comment: Pas de problème, j'ai fait un *rollback*. Je te laisse corriger l'étourderie qui subsiste...

Comment: Ha! Oui! Là, ce n'est pas pareil. L'étourderie était assurément disgracieuse et je te remercie de me l'avoir signalée.

Comment: il y a toujours le problèmes des haricots verts :D

Answer (score -5):

Le H (positionné en première lettre d'un mot) est muet par défaut.

Comment: La question est de savoir si on fait l'élision (ou la liaison) ou pas.

Comment: @A STEFANI : On devrait certainement pouvoir prendre ta contribution en illustration de l'adjectif... *laconique*. Tu dis "*par défaut*"... ??? à défaut... de quoi ??? SI (et seulement si) c'est : **à défaut de savoir** comment les locaux expriment leurs toponymes, **à défaut de savoir** comment un individu exprime son patronyme alors ce que tu postules pourrait faire sens. Au nom d'un *principe de précaution* (l'hiatus postulé disgracieux) on ne prend pas le risque de l'insinuer => élision. Cela se tient mais... il nous faudrait plus de précisions et de références.