# Is there an online dictionary with phonemic notations regarding liaison and elision for words like uhlan or onze?

Tags: liaisons, élision, dictionnaires, h-aspiré

Is there an online dictionary with phonemic notations regarding liaison and elision for words like uhlan or onze? I've heard that these words aren't affected by liaison and elision, but I haven't found an online dictionary that explicitly says so. [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/) seems to only help with aspirate h's (by adding an asterisk, for exampl *héros), but not with these words.

Answer (score 3):

Tous les dictionnaires de qualité donnent cette information.

Elle n'est cependant pas formulée de façon explicite il est vrai mais il suffit de lire l'article dans lequel des exemples sont donnés pour comprendre.

Par exemple, dans le Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française, à la vedette [ONZE](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/onze?page=1) tu pourras lire dans l'article : "*Bouillon **d**'onze heures... Miser sur **le** onze. Aux courses, parier sur **le** onze...*" que je trouve éloquents.

EDIT : Nota : L'information ne peut être donnée explicitement et n'apparait que dans des exemples car il n'est pas question de règle intangible. Il n'est que question d'usage et, en la matière, [il change... souvent et vite](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31119/comment-savoir-utiliser-h-muet-ou-h-aspir%C3%A9-dans-les-noms-de-gens/31120#31120).